# delay of receiving data from a gprs connection

Tags: c#, networkstream

I am writing a parser in C#. It receives and sends a packet with `max length = 100`. However, the time between (receiving and sending) after each packet is more than 2 seconds. I don't know whether it is a problem of my implementation or the gprs side.

Server listening:

```
tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Names.comPort);
tcpListener.Server.NoDelay = true;

while (true)
{
    TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

    Thread th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleComm));
    th.IsBackground = true;
    th.start(client);
}
```

Begin receiving data:

```
HandleComm(object client)
{
 NetworkStream clientStream = ((TcpClient)client).GetStream();

 while (true)
 {
     try { bytesRead = clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, 200);}
     catch(Exception ex) {break;}        
 }
}
```

It is a simple implementation, the moment I receive the bytesRead of the first data packet compared to the second one is about 2s. It is too slow I think. How could I increase receiving time? I already checked after receiving data and replying, it took 1 ms only.

Adding sending part:

```
socket.NoDelay = true;
socket.SendTimeout = 200; // minimum time out
socket.SendBufferSize = bytes.Length;

socket.Send(bytes, SocketFlags.DontRoute);
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code, except that it's not very efficient to create one thread per socket if you have a lot of clients. It's more interesting to see the sender code.

Comment: @jgauffin, I added the sending part as well. Why it is not very efficient to create one thread per socket? because then I can handle each socket connection in one thread? because there are more than 100 connections at the same time.

Comment: Read about BeginSend/EndSend at MSDN (google "BeginSend MSDN"). It's more efficient. Why do you specify a SendTimeout? Do you really understand what it does?

Comment: GPRS has an inherent long latency. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: jgauffin: I replaced with beginSend but the performance is not improved. Why it is more efficient to use the BeginSend method?

Comment: leppie: really? my client told me that another GPRS parser is working faster 800ms instead of 2 seconds as my version.  SO I need to find a way to optimize it.